# How I can do a read-only input field

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

[image]

I tried this code but didn't work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control"
           id="form Control Read only"
           type="text"
           value="Read only input here..."
           aria-label="readonly input example"
           readonly />
    <label class="form-label" for="formControlReadonly">Readonly</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine other than the missing [floating label](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/floating-labels) classes. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `readonly` attribute makes the input field just for reading but still can be selected. The `disabled` attribute will disable all the things(disable selectable mode and editable mode). Try [disabled](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/textbox/how-to/set-the-disabled-state/) in your input attributes.

By the way after you make disabled true the input field is just for shown.

Comment: i want to make label show in input area

Comment: You should make the label absolute and the input relative then move label to your target position.

Comment: how I can do that if you have example some of code to help me Regrads

Comment: Use this code:
`<fieldset><legend>readOnly</legend></fieldset>`

Comment: But if you want an input field to be in that style I developed something for you in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-roentgen-g5bt78?file=/src/App.js)